# Python Pandas: Add values to another column

Tags: python, pandas, row, addition

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 |
| 15 | 25 |
| 05 | 30 |
| 33 | 63 |

How to generate Col2 out of a given Col1

Comment: Can you please give more details of what you want? You have Col1 and you want to create Col2? What is the logic you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum`:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].cumsum()
df
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2
0    10    10
1    15    25
2     5    30
3    33    63
```